# Json result with "undefined" prefixed

Tags: node.js

I use node https module to get auth information from another server, I get the result is "result=undefined{a:...,b:...}", so I can't use JSON.parse to parse the result data, but if I use "JSON.parse(body.substr(9))", I can get the right result. 
For more information, if I use a post tool to fetch the result, I get the result type is "application/json" and the result is the right json object. I use the following code to fetch post result.

```
 var options={
    hostname:...,
    port:null,
    path:...,
    method:'post',
    rejectUnauthorized:false,
    requestCert:true,
    agent:false
  }
  var https.request(options,function(res){
    var body;

    res.on('data',function(chunk){
       body+=chunk;
    });

    res.on('end',function(){
       console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `body` with an empty string:

```
var body = '';
```

because otherwise, the first time

```
body+=chunk;
```

is called, `body` is `undefined` and gets concatenated as the `"undefined"` string:

```
> var body;
undefined
> body += "{}"
'undefined{}'
> var body = '';
undefined
> body += "{}"
'{}'
```

Comment: Well, I solved the problem myself, the problem is not there, chunk is not string type, so there is no need to initialize an empty string, but still thanks for the answer. The return of the url is not clean, this causes the "undefined" problem, the post plugin of firefox handles it itself, so the result is correct in post tool.